# Getting the returned object in retrofit and rxjava

Tags: android, json, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I'm going to use rxjava with retrofit in my app. The thing that i'm dealing with his that: i use this json format on my POST API to send data to server:

```
{
    "user":{
        "email":"0665587777",
        "password":"password",
        "password_confirmation":"password",
        "user_type":"patient"
    },
    "profile":{
        "first_name":"David",
        "lastname":"Jackson bil",
        "gender":"Male",
        "national_id":"22111"
    }
}
```

and get this json format to get data from server:

```
{
  "id": 37,
  "email": "0665587777",
  "created_at": "2017-05-12T13:11:58.278Z",
  "updated_at": "2017-05-12T13:11:58.278Z",
  "enabled": false,
  "admin": false,
  "user_type": "patient",
  "googletoken": null
}
```

for this i created a object named register and implement like this:

```
public class register {
    @SerializedName("user")
    User user=new User();
    @SerializedName("profile")
    patient patient=new patient();
}
```

I set API call like this in my Interface:

```
 @POST("api/users")
        //Call<SOAnswersResponse> getAnswer();
    Observable<register> CreateUser(@Body register user);
```

and implement Retrofit client like this:

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit=null;
    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl){
        if(retrofit==null){
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

and this is what everything that i did in my activity:

```
public class CreateUser extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SOService mService;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user);

        mService= ApiUtils.getSOService();
        loadAnwser();
    }
    private void loadAnwser() {

        Observer<register> myObserver= new Observer<register>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull register register) {
               User user=register.getUser();
               Log.d("Retroit_Result",user.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
               Log.d("Retroit_Result","Error"+e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        };
        mService=ApiUtils.getSOService();
        User user=new User();
        patient patient=new patient();
        register reg=new register();

        patient.setFirst_name("Hussssein");
        patient.setLast_name("Ojaaaghi");
        user.setEmail("55662266");
        patient.setGender("Male");
        patient.setNational_id("123222322");
        user.setPassword("password");
        user.setPassword_confirmation("password");
        user.setUser_type("patient");
        reg.setPatient(patient);
        reg.setUser(user);
        mService.CreateUser(reg)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(myObserver);
    }
}
```

now the problem is that i get null in my onNext method?

Answer (score 0):

You are POSTing a register object but also expecting the API call to return a register object e.g.

```
Observable<register> CreateUser(@Body register user);
```

however the JSON snippet your expecting isn't a register type

{
  "id": 37,
  "email": "0665587777",
  "created_at": "2017-05-12T13:11:58.278Z",
  "updated_at": "2017-05-12T13:11:58.278Z",
  "enabled": false,
  "admin": false,
  "user_type": "patient",
  "googletoken": null
}

You need to create a new response object representing this data and change the return type e.g.

```
Observable<RegisterResponse> CreateUser(@Body register user);
```

Comment: so what should i have to do on loadAnwser method, i did this before but the real problem was with loadAnwser method, i don't know how to declare observable and subscribe in there

Comment: So in loadAnswer your subscriber will start like this:
    Observer<RegisterResponse> myObserver= new 
    Observer<RegisterResponse>() {
i.e. change register to RegisterResponse in all places or whatever you call the response class

Answer (score 0):

```
public class register {
    @SerializedName("user")
    User user=new User();
    @SerializedName("profile")
    patient patient=new patient();
}
```

Dont instantiate objects like this, Gson adapter will do this for you

Instad your model class should look like this

```
public class register {

        @SerializedName("user")
        User user;

        @SerializedName("profile")
        patient patient;

        public User getUser() {
            return this.user;
        }

        public patient getpatient() {
            return this.patient;
        }
    }
```

Optionaly if you want to manually create objects of your `register` class create consturctor that will suit your needs

One side note, try following [java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) so your code will be more readable